# WordPress - Unable to Create New Account - Windows/Apache/MySQL

Tags: apache

I have WordPress on a self hosted Windows Server running Apache and MySQL.
I am unable to create a new user directly from the Dashboard.
I know about disabling new user registration, this is happening when I am logged in as an admin like I mentioned earlier in the dashboard and directly creating the account.

Any idea where I can look for why this might be happening?  Existing users work fine, nothing wrong with the site, everyone who already had an account can post articles and update pages.  It's just that I cannot create any new accounts.

Comment: Can you check your server error logs? Can you set debug to true in wp-config? That might give you a starting point.

Comment: if it does not work, what does it do instead? Like Niki mentoned check your error logs, right now theres not enough information here to write an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to create new user accounts directly from the WordPress dashboard as an admin, try these troubleshooting steps:

Disable plugins and switch to a default theme to check for conflicts.

Verify your admin account has the correct role and capabilities.

Look for error messages during the user creation process.

Check server logs for relevant error entries.

Confirm database connectivity and update credentials if needed.
Check file and directory permissions.

Clear caches, including caching plugins or server-side caching.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and I do not believe it is technical, it is that I did not understand multi-user sites.  I had to go to the parent site to create the account.  I thought I should be able to do it directly on one of the child (not sure if that is correct terminology) sites.  This is my first multi-user WP installation; it threw me off a bit.